# How to animate zooming UIView WITH SUBVIEWS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

This code does the following: It takes a 'snapshot' of a NavigationController meant to disappear. Then the snapshot is added to the view of a container view controller, slides away and reveals the new NavigationController. To create the 'Pop-Out-Effect' the *midAnFrame* makes the view a bit bigger than the actual view. After that *postAnFrame* provides the sliding out of the container view's frame. Works great, the only problem is that the subviews of *animationContainer* don't resize like their superView during the animation.

```
- (void)bringUpSettingsNavigationController {
CGFloat gradientWidth = 20;
CGFloat frameIncrease = 10;
CGRect preAnFrame  = CGRectMake(- gradientWidth, 0, self.view.frame.size.width + gradientWidth, self.view.frame.size.height);
CGRect midAnFrame  = CGRectMake(-(frameIncrease + gradientWidth), - frameIncrease, preAnFrame.size.width + (2*frameIncrease), preAnFrame.size.height + (2*frameIncrease));
CGRect postAnFrame = CGRectMake(midAnFrame.size.width, midAnFrame.origin.y, midAnFrame.size.width, midAnFrame.size.height);

UIView *animationContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:preAnFrame];
animationContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
animationContainer.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

self.topImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[self topImageFromView:self.view]];
self.topImageView.frame = CGRectMake(gradientWidth, 0, preAnFrame.size.width - gradientWidth, preAnFrame.size.height);
[animationContainer addSubview:self.topImageView];
self.topImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIView *gradientView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, gradientWidth, preAnFrame.size.height)];
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds;
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5] CGColor], nil];
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
[gradientView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
gradientView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[animationContainer addSubview:gradientView];
gradientView.clipsToBounds = YES;

[self.view addSubview:animationContainer];

BYSettingsNavigationController *settingsNavigationController = [[BYSettingsNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[[BYSettingsViewController alloc]init]];
[self addChildViewController:settingsNavigationController];
settingsNavigationController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view insertSubview:settingsNavigationController.view belowSubview:animationContainer];
[settingsNavigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    animationContainer.frame = midAnFrame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        animationContainer.frame = postAnFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.topImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [gradientView removeFromSuperview];
        self.topImageView = nil;
    }];
}];

[self.currentNavigationController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.currentNavigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.currentNavigationController removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

[image: check the lower right corner]

Thanks in advance for your ideas and have a great 2013!

Dario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your doing is not zooming in , your just changing the frame size.
To zoom in you need to change the transformation of the view.

What you need to do is something along this line:

`view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (2.0 , 2.0);`

for example to zoom X2